# Which is more efficient to add indices in list of dict?

Tags: python, list

I want to add indices to this list of dict:

```
wallets = [
    {'balance': 1500},
    {'balance': 12},
    {'balance': 0}
]
```

It should be like that:

```
wallets = [
    {'index':0, 'balance': 1500},
    {'index':1, 'balance': 12},
    {'index':2, 'balance': 0}
]
```

Now i'm using this solution:

```
wallets = [dict([('index', index)] + list(w.items())) for index, w in enumerate(wallets)]
```

Which is more efficient and Pythonic-way solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not going a simple way:

```
for i in xrange(len(wallets)):
    wallets[i]["index"] = i
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the extent of the data you're storing, you don't need a `list` of `dict`s at all. You can just use an ordinary `list`.

```
wallets = [1500, 12, 0]
```

Instead of checking each `dict`'s "index" value for the entry you want, just use that value to directly access the `list`, e.g. `wallets[0]` would give you `1500`.

Comment: there is another fields, not only 'balance', thank you